# find all imported file names from a source file with regexp javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

i am new to regex and javascript.
i am trying to create an array of all imported files of a source file using regex.
before an import statement there will be a '@' sign as well. for example:

if the file looks like

> ...
> @import file1,file2,     file3; 
> int i=6;
>  @import     file4;
> ...

then i need an array with [file1,file2,file3,file4]

so far i have tried to create the reg exp itself with no success.
any help with that ?
Thanks
*edited to make things more clear*

Comment: See my answer with complex solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complex solution for your question (+demo):

```js
function run() {
  
  var 
    re = /(?:@import)\s+([^;]+)/igm,
    str = document.getElementById('demo').value,
    arr = [];

  while (result = re.exec(str)) {

    arr = arr.concat(result[1].split(/[,\s]+/))
  }

  //console.log(arr);
  
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(arr);
}
```

```html
<p>
  <textarea id="demo" cols="50" rows="15">

  // .....
  
  @import file1,file2, file3; 
  
  int i=6;
    
  @import file4;
  
  // .....
  </textarea>
</p>
<p>
  <span id="result" style="color:green;"></span>
</p>
<p>
  <input type="button" value="RUN" onclick="run()">
</p>
```

Run my demo, to see the result.

Comment: hi, thank you ! As i mentioned i was talking about a source file, therefore it might (and probably) have many other statements inside. i need the array to include only the imported files. an example of unwanted behaviour would be if str = "@import file1,; i=6; @import file2;"

Comment: @Amitk, Hi. I have updated my answer and now It can parse and extract file names from your source codes. You can try any example in my demo. Check plz if It is ok for you. Let me know plz the results.

Comment: works like charm. thank you very much for your help :) answer was accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.prototype.split()` with `RegExp` `/@import|,|;|\s/`, `Array.prototype.filter()` with parameter `Boolean`

```
text.split(/@import|,|;|\s/).filter(Boolean)
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/OpLBFMehRjC1sm1GA9BL?p=preview

Comment: Result: ["file1", "file2", "file3;", "file4;"]. `;`?

Comment: @AliMamedov include `;` in alternation

Comment: hi, thank you ! As i mentioned i was talking about a source file, therefore it might (and probably) have many other statements inside. i need the array to include only the imported files. an example of unwanted behaviour would be if str = "@import file1,; i=6; @import file2;"  **updated the post to be more clear about it**

Comment: @Amitk Would `i = 6` be on same line as `@import` ? Do all files begin with `"file"` string? Can you update Question to include accurate representation of file contents?